# How to getMeasuredWidth() when weights are set

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I have made a simple example to ilustrate the problem. Here is a simple LinearLayout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/ll"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
</LinearLayout>
```

and then I populate it in onCreate()

```
private final String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();

ImageView iv1;
ImageView iv2;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    lp.weight=1.0f;

    iv1 = new ImageView(this);
    iv1.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);

    iv2 = new ImageView(this);
    iv2.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);

    container.addView(iv1, lp);
    container.addView(iv2, lp);

    container.measure(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
    Log.d(TAG, " measured width(1): " + iv1.getMeasuredWidth());
    Log.d(TAG, " measured width(2): " + iv2.getMeasuredWidth());
```

where icon is a simple image of 48x48dp. question is: why getMeasuredWidth returns 48 in Logs, but when i look in hierarchy viewer mMeasureWidth is 160? In other words the real question is .. how can I get real width/height (in Java) of the view when it is stretched in a LinearLayout ? Calling requestLayout(), measure() does not work. I could try to get a sum of weigths and calculate everything that LinearLayout does, but maybe there is a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 2):

onCreate is called much before the activity is displayed.

Therefore, iv1.getMeasuredWidth() is not yet the value you expect and should be called in another method, later. I think onWindowFocusChange is correct.

Comment: this is quite confusing. If I can call measure() on all of the LinearLayout's children and it returns correct results, why would I have to wait for another method to be invoked (say onWindowFocusChange) to get my result. I mean, at any given time when i have children of the LinearLayout and thier weights this value (real width/height) should be accessible.

Comment: yes, but no. the dimensions varies with screen size and orientation changes, as well as when other components change their own size.

Comment: okay, I've made some quick tests and onWindowFocusChange seems to work (by the time it is called width is actually 160). Problem is that this method is not guaranteed to be called (say your activity is actually creating a dialog in onCreate()), plus it cannot be 'placed' anywhere in the lifecycle (please refer to docummentation)

However, I've also found a workaround for this problem. Namely by adding a ViewTreeObserver onPreDrawListener.

Comment: you are right, onWindowFocusChanged is far from perfect (although it works good enough for me), and your solution seems good